# during execution master detail flow i get 2 errors 1-Error:(77, 24) error: cannot find symbol class ItemListActivity

Tags: android-studio

```
public static class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final  ItemListActivity mParentActivity;
    private final List<DummyContent.DummyItem> mValues;
    private final boolean mTwoPane;
    private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DummyContent.DummyItem item = (DummyContent.DummyItem) view.getTag();
            if (mTwoPane) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(WebpageDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, item.id);
                WebpageDetailFragment fragment = new WebpageDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);

                mParentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.webpage_detail_container, fragment)
                        .commit();
```

Answer (score 14):

This happens when you change the default item names during the wizard of creating the activity.
just rename the `ItemListActivity`  to the name of your Activity . ( the name of the file that  has that code error). 
use refactor rename to change it  everywhere it's mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If the ItemListActivity (or whatever you ended up calling it) extends from Activity and not AppCompatActivity then try changing the line

`mParentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()`

to

`mParentActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()`